# How clean is my snow?

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, console, animation

I just wrote a snow animation in Python. I think this is fairly clean but I have a few things that I don't like.

```
from random import randrange
import time

# Snow animation
# Snow is simply the `#` symbol here. Half of the snow moves at 1 char
# per frame, while the other half moves at 0.5 chars per frame. The
# program ends when all the snow reaches the bottom of the screen.
# The viewing area is 80x25. It puts 100 snow flakes to output, half
# fast, and half slow. Every frame it dispenses 4 flakes, 2 fast and
# 2 slow ones, at random locations at the top of the viewing area.

screen = {'x': 80, 'y': 20}
drops = []

def createRainDrop(x, y, speed):
    return {'x': x, 'y': y, 'speed': speed}

def createRandomDrops():
    dropCount = 4
    for i in range(dropCount):
        yield createRainDrop(randrange(0, screen['x']), 0, min((i % 2) + 0.5, 1))

def moveDrops():
    for drop in drops:
        speed = drop['speed']
        drop['y'] = drop['y']+speed

def drawDrops():
    out = [''] * screen['y']
    for y in range(screen['y']):
      for x in range(screen['x']):
        out[y] += '#' if any([drop['x'] == x and int(drop['y']) == y for drop in drops]) else ' '

    return '\n'.join(out)


def dropsOnScreen():
    return any([drop['y'] < screen['y'] for drop in drops])

drops += createRandomDrops()

while dropsOnScreen():
    if len(drops) < 100:
        drops += createRandomDrops()

    print(drawDrops())
    moveDrops()
    time.sleep(0.100)
```

For example, I don't know how to remove the duplicate line `drops += createRandomDrops()`, and `drawDrops()` feels a bit like a hack.

<sub>I confess! While writing this it was rain, not snow!</sub>

Comment: `createRainDrop` are you sure that's snow falling?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. While writing this it was rain, not snow.

Comment: I would love to see the animation. What do I need to follow to "load" the code on a Windows 7 machine please? Can I just install Python and let the file run with it or do I need an IDE and run it inside that? Any link to a tut on how to get this started would be nice. Currently it is "snow-raining" here, half snow half rain.

Comment: Just install python 3.x, go to the console and type `python C:\path\to\snow.py`. You may need to shrink the console window for the animation to be smooth(ish).

Comment: Newbie question: can a "Run code snippet" (cf. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64176/136168) be added to this question? If not, how would you suggest running the script: locally or on some online platform (if so, which)?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Let's look at the code.

```
from random import randrange
import time
```

Your imports are very minimal! Good.

```
# Snow animation
# Snow is simply the `#` symbol here. Half of the snow moves at 1 char
# per frame, while the other half moves at 0.5 chars per frame. The
# program ends when all the snow reaches the bottom of the screen.
# The viewing area is 80x25. It puts 100 snow flakes to output, half
# fast, and half slow. Every frame it dispenses 4 flakes, 2 fast and
# 2 slow ones, at random locations at the top of the viewing area.
```

This looks more like a docstring to me. It would be nice to render it as such. You can do this by dropping the `#` signs, and surrounding it in `"""` quotes.

```
screen = {'x': 80, 'y': 20}
drops = []
```

Global variables are not that nice. But this is a simple file, so maybe we can leave it like this for now? Let's.

```
def createRainDrop(x, y, speed):
    return {'x': x, 'y': y, 'speed': speed}
```

I think something like a class would be better for this. Let's try

```
class RainDrop(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
```

Of course, now we need to replace `createRainDrop(...)` with `RainDrop(...)`, and `drop['...']` with `drop....`.

```
def createRandomDrops():
    dropCount = 4
    for i in range(dropCount):
        yield RainDrop(randrange(0, screen['x']), 0, min((i % 2) + 0.5, 1))
```

That's better.

```
def moveDrops():
    for drop in drops:
        drop.y = drop.y + drop.speed
```

We're modifying `drop` here, instead of asking it to modify itself. We should be writing something like `drop.moveDown()` here, or maybe `drop.tick()` ('tick' is what's commonly used to notify an event about stepping forward in time).

```
def drawDrops():
    out = [''] * screen['y']
    for y in range(screen['y']):
      for x in range(screen['x']):
        out[y] += '#' if any([drop.x == x and drop.y == y for drop in drops]) else ' '

    return '\n'.join(out)
```

Here, for all the positions on the screen, you're looping over all the drops. Ideally we'd turn that around:

```
def drawDrops():
    out = [[' ' for _ in range(screen['x'])] for _ in range(screen['y'])]
    for drop in drops:
        if int(drop.y) < screen['y']:
            out[int(drop.y)][drop.x] = '#'
```

Now that's a bit faster and cleaner.

```
def dropsOnScreen():
    return any([drop.y < screen['y'] for drop in drops])
```

Makes sense. Except I'd suggest to not use the `[...]`, which creates a list. Better to use

```
def dropsOnScreen():
     return any(drop.y < screen['y'] for drop in drops)
```

This behaves the same, but does not have to create an intermediate list.

```
drops += createRandomDrops()

while dropsOnScreen():
    if len(drops) < 100:
        drops += createRandomDrops()

    print(drawDrops())
    moveDrops()
    time.sleep(0.100)
```

You want to get rid of the duplicated call to `drops += createRandomDrops()`.

```
while True:
    if len(drops) < 100:
        drops += createRandomDrops()

    if not dropsOnScreen():
        break

    print(drawDrops())
    moveDrops()
    time.sleep(0.100)
```

But in my opinion, the extra `createRandomDrops` is not that bad.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This does look much better than my original code. A minor point: in `createRandomDrops` you point out the  `min((i % 2) + 0.5, 1)` and change it to `min(int(i % 2 + 0.5), 1)`, the original was actually intended to use floats, it changes a number to `1` or `0.5` so I could get a half step snow flake, though it is a bit  hard to tell...

Comment: A rather off topic question, is it more common in python to see `snake_cased_names` or `camelCaseNames`? (I think the python style guide uses `snake_case`, though personally I like `camelCase` much better)

Comment: @JAtkin: snake-case, except for classes which should be PascalCase.

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus your remark on `y`, it is not `y`, it is speed.

Comment: @njzk2: thanks. I'll take time to fix it tomorrow. Or maybe you can propose an edit?

Comment: `out[drop.y][drop.x] = '#'` requires a prior test, because the drops are exiting the screen at some point

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus I'm not sure what the intent of the OP is regarding the speed. It looks like it should be `0.5` or `1`, so maybe `(1.0, 0.5)[i%2]`

Comment: @njzk2: after re-reading, the statement is `min((i % 2) + 0.5, 1)`. This takes values `(1.0, 1.5)[i % 2]`. It might not be what is intended, but it is the current value.

Comment: @njzk2: you're totally right about the out-of-bounds check regarding `drop.y` during drawing. I was pondering suggesting automated drop removal, but that clashes with the counting to 100.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, `out[drop.y][drop.x] = '#'` require a test does, when I rewrote my code I noticed this exact problem. The intent of the speed was to get `0.5` and `1` speed flakes. The flakes that are halfway between pixels are rounded down with `int()`, and only move every other frame. `min((i % 2) + 0.5, 1)` is rather clumsy, but I couldn't think of anything better at the moment.

Comment: @JAtkin `(0.5, 1)[i%2]` is a little more compact for the speed selection.

Comment: Your version of `drawDrops()` uses two list generator expressions with underscore dummy variables to initialize `out`. This is not very expressive – I'd suggest to use the much faster and more explicit alternative `out = [[' '] * screen['x']] * screen['y']`instead.

Comment: @Schmuddi: Please consider `out = [[' '] * 7] * 5` followed by `out[3][4] = 'X'`. Then, `out[2][4]` will also be set to `X`, as `out[0]`..`out[4]` all reference the same list. A valid alternative might be `out = [[' '] * screen[x'] for _ in range(screen['y'])]`.

Comment: Wow... yes, you're right – I stand corrected. Now, I remember using this type of code for a simple tile-based game years ago in Python 2.1. Has this behavior changed over time?

Comment: @Schmuddi: As far as I know it has always been the same. `[value] * 5` creates a list of 5 entries each referring to the same object, not 5 copies of the object.

Answer (score 61):

Cool animation!

Let's get some linting out of the way.  As per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should use 4 spaces of indentation consistently, and function names should be `snake_case`.

### Scalability

The main weakness of your design is scalability.  If you extend the loop to run indefinitely, then you will eventually run into performance issues.

One problem is that the `drops` list **grows with each iteration**, and is never pruned.  The drops don't disappear after falling to the ground; they keep falling forever, invisibly, off-screen.  The solution is to have `moveDrops()` delete drops when they fall beyond the bottom.  (That's a smarter strategy than having `dropsOnScreen()` re-examine every drop on every animation frame.)

Furthermore, to place the drops on the grid, you do an **O(*n*) scan for each position on the screen** with `'#' if any([drop['x'] == x and int(drop['y']) == y for drop in drops])`.  I would rewrite `drawDrops()` so that each drop places itself, using a dictionary or a 2-D array.  I would also prefer to use comprehensions than repeated append operations, but that is mostly a style preference.

### Data types

Your comment says that the **screen dimensions** are 80×25, but your code says `screen = {'x': 80, 'y': 20}`.  Ideally, the dimensions should be detected at runtime using the `curses` library.  Since `screen` is used as a **global** variable, I would like to see it named `SCREEN` and made immutable.  A `namedtuple` would make it immutable, with the additional benefit of allowing the dot accessor rather than the clumsy `[]` notation.  I think that `width` and `height` would be more appropriate names than `x` and `y`.

Similarly, defining a **class** for the raindrops would avoid the `drop['x']` notation.  Furthermore, the `createRainDrop()` function cries out to be a constructor.

### Creating drops and looping

The rest of the code is an exercise in Pythonic iteration.  Everything can be handled with liberal usage of iterators.

In `createRandomDrops()`, instead of the **cryptic formula** `min((i % 2) + 0.5, 1)`, use `itertools.cycle([0.5, 1])`.  I would turn `createRandomDrops()` into an infinite generator.

In the solution below, parameters such as the speed, intensity, and duration are all **centrally tweakable** by modifying `drop_params` and `precipitation`.  For example, `precipitation = drop_generator(**drop_params)` would result in an infinite loop with just one new drop per frame.

### Suggested solution

```
from collections import namedtuple
import curses
from itertools import chain, cycle, islice, repeat
from random import randrange
import sys
import time

SCREEN = namedtuple('Screen', 'height width')(*curses.initscr().getmaxyx())
curses.endwin()

class Raindrop:
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
        self.x, self.y, self.speed = x, y, speed

def drop_generator(batch_size=1, **drop_params):
    while True:
        yield [
            Raindrop(**{key: next(gen) for key, gen in drop_params.items()})
            for _ in range(batch_size)
        ]

def move_drops(drops):
    """Move each drop down according to its speed, and remove drops from the
       set that have fallen off."""
    for drop in drops:
        drop.y += drop.speed
    drops.difference_update([drop for drop in drops if drop.y >= SCREEN.height])

def render_drops(drops, char='#'):
    """Return a string representation of the entire screen."""
    scr = {
        int(drop.y) * SCREEN.width + int(drop.x): char for drop in drops
    }
    return '\n'.join(
        ''.join(scr.get(y * SCREEN.width + x, ' ') for x in range(SCREEN.width))
        for y in range(SCREEN.height)
    )


drop_params = {
    'x': (randrange(0, SCREEN.width) for _ in repeat(True)),
    'y': repeat(0),
    'speed': cycle([0.5, 1]),
}
precipitation = chain.from_iterable([
    islice(drop_generator(batch_size=4, **drop_params), 25),
    repeat([])  # ... then generate nothing as existing drops keep falling
])
drops = set(next(precipitation))
while drops:
    drops.update(next(precipitation))
    print(render_drops(drops))
    # Python 2.7 seems to have a curses bug that necessitates flushing
    sys.stdout.flush()
    move_drops(drops)
    time.sleep(0.100)
```

Comment: Very nice! Apparently my _cryptic formula_ was really bad, because it returns `0.5` and `1`... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118538/how-clean-is-my-snow/118622#comment220871_118544 I personally dislike the `snake_case` very much (I come from Java/Scala) and that is why I was using `camelCase`. **Edit**, woah, I can hardly read your solution. I'm gonna go and find my python book...

Comment: @JAtkin since you're using Python3, why not just use the [builtin terminal size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14422538/344286)?

Comment: 2 reasons. 1) I didn't know about it. 2) I came by the current numbers by trial and error to get the least flickering on my machine.

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe also wrap the code with an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard?

Answer (score 37):

You don't get `drops` of snow! Clearly it should be

```
  for flake in flurry:
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why (what seems to be to me) pedantry is the second most up-voted answer to this question. Granted, the English lexical difference is important to the next code maintainer, a 100-character answer regarding 2 variable names seems to be of less value than every other answer here. CR community, you confuse me.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice You are not the only one confused by this. If you want, feel free to post a question on our meta. Unfortunately(?), nitpicking on a variable name **is** a valid answer. As to why it has been upvoted this much, I can't say.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice and Simon well the original question is asking about some nitpicks in a script that draws snow on the screen. most people probably don't see the serious vibe in that either

Comment: Naming things is one of the two hard problems in computer science so 'nit picking' names is quite important. For reference the hard problems are 1) Naming things 2) Cache expiry 3) off by one errors. I think the alliteration got an upboat or two too.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I posted a [question on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/should-pedantry-be-discouraged). I don't think that this answer should be deleted or anything, but answers like this that seem to be funny remarks should really be comments in my opinion, and not shadow other *complete* answers.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Sometimes we cannot see the forrest from staring at certain trees. This answer is funny and positive and brief and is contributing perspective. I first spent time with two serious answers, and when I came to this one, I just loved it. The number of upvotes is not a measure of the "value" of an answer, but of people who decided that they "like" this answer in this context.

Answer (score 30):

I'm surprised no one has talked about your character choice! Why are their a bunch of hashtags falling? Nah, I kid, it was an ok choice of character, but we can do better! What about changing the `#` to the unicode ([which Python 3 supports!](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html)) `❄`. Now it really looks like snow!

Also, your code at the moment is backwards compatible with Python 2. My change of character would break that. If you want to fix that add:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

To the top of your file.

Comment: In case you're not sure how to type that, or don't feel like searching, `print('\N{SNOWFLAKE}')` should help. Also it works on Python2, if you make that `u'\N{SNOWFLAKE}'` ;)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that utf-8 had a snow symbol.

Answer (score 21):

```
def createRandomDrops():
    dropCount = 4
    for i in range(dropCount):
```

Magic number 4 in middle of the code

```
def drawDrops():
```

I would expect this method to actually draw drops, not return string to print

Answer (score 10):

```
from random import randrange
```

I would suggest using

```
import random
```

Then in your code use `random.randrange`. In your particular case maybe it doesn't really matter, but I've found for myself that it's a good rule to import the module, when possible, instead of names from it.

https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Imports

> Use `import`s for packages and modules only.

Importing modules sometimes helps you to prevent circular import errors.

It helps importing too many names when your module grows.

It helps you solving name clashes. For example several modules have `ValidationError` class (`mongoengine`, `wtforms`, etc.) and your code uses all of them.